# Select output won't display before substitution variable prompt

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do something like:

```
SELECT * From stock ; 
Define input ; 
insert into STOCK values(&input) ; 
commit ;
```

My problem is that the result of the select does not appear in the script output window until after the prompt pop-up has been shown to get the user `input` value from the user.

The idea is that the user can look at the table for a missing entry and then insert values that the user wants. After viewing the select the user will then be prompted for input, enter the values needed and then commit.

How can I make it show the query result before prompting?

Comment: whats your input value?

Comment: The select does not appear where? I don't really understand what you're asking, or doing. How are you running this, and from where? Were you intending to *prompt* for an input rather than define it before run-time? What if no inserts are needed, or multiple values need to be inserted? What do you mean by 'transaction' in the title?

Comment: The input value is user defined . User enters into a prompt box . 
The select does not appear in the script output. i would like to be able to view the out put from the select and then insert into the table.At the moment it opens the prompt box for input before showing the output from the select

Comment: So you're running this as a script in SQL Developer, right? I don't see that behaviour with what you've posted, in 4.1.3; though I do without the (incorrect) `define` line. It seems to need *something*, even a comment line, between the select and the line that uses the substitution variable, which I guess is something to do with how it's parsing the script into statements.

Comment: Yes i was intending to prompt.  The idea is that the user can run the transaction and view the output of the select.(stock in this case) then after viewing the table insert values into the table and then commit at the end of it

Comment: yes in SQL developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what you're describing in SQL Developer 4.1.3 unless I remove the `define` line, which isn't doing anything useful anyway.

When the `select` is followed immediately by the `insert` the prompt for the substitution does indeed pop up before the query output is shown in the script output window. So with this script the prompt comes first:

```
SELECT * From stock ; 
insert into STOCK values(&input) ;
```

Putting anything except whitespace between them seems to 'fix' it, even a comment line, so this script displays the results in the script output window before prompting:

```
SELECT * From stock ;
--
insert into STOCK values(&input) ;
```

You can also use an `accept` command:

```
SELECT * From stock ;
accept input prompt 'New value'
insert into STOCK values(&input) ;
```

Presumably this is something to do with how SQL Developer is parsing the script into statements and processing each in turn. It's possible earlier versions of SQL Developer behave differently of course, so you may still be seeing it with the `define` line - though that just generates a message like "SP2-0135: symbol INPUT is UNDEFINED" in the script window, again after the prompt unless there is something between the define and the insert.

What you're doing doesn't really make much sense though, as it doesn't allow for the user deciding they don't actually want/need to insert anything, and if they see more than one value missing they have to run the whole script again. The client isn't really designed for interactive user input like this, and you'd be better off using an application layer to do this - a shell or command script, or Apex, or PHP etc.

Comment: so in the second code snippet you posted it displays the results of the select and then opens the prompt ? I dont not get the same results just the input prompt opening before select is displayed. 

Yes i do see its not the most useful idea  we have not covered
" The client isn't really designed for interactive user input like this, and you'd be better off using an application layer to do this - a shell or command script, or Apex, or PHP etc." yet as it is just an intro module for next year when we pick our modules

Comment: @Broomer - yes, that's what happens for me. Which version of SQL Developer are you using? And does adding an extra comment line between the select (or the define if you keep that) and the insert, and/or blank lines, affect the behaviour?

Comment: hi , 
im using   4.1.3.20  , no none of the things you mention change the behaviour?

Comment: Hmm, then I can't think of a reason it would behave differently for you. How about the `accept` command I just added? Maybe with a comment line before it?

Comment: Hi, restarted sql devoloper and it seems to be working. 
Thanks for your help .